# Polymer 1.0 template bind ref equivalent

Tags: polymer

In Polymer 0.5, you could do:

```
<template bind ref="howdyTpl"></template>
...
<template id="howdyTpl">Howdy {{whatever}}</template>
```

And the template with id 'howdyTpl' would get stamped where referenced in the `ref` attribute.

How can I do something similar in Polymer 1.0?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a custom element that does something similar.

```
Polymer({
  is: 'bind-ref',

  properties: {
    ref: {
      type: String,
      observer: 'refChanged',
    },
  },

  refChanged: function(newRef, oldRef) {
    if (oldRef != undefined) {
      this._removeChildren();
      this._stamp();
    }
  },

  _stamp: function() {
    this._parent = Polymer.dom(this).parentNode;
    var rootEl = this._parent;
    while (Polymer.dom(rootEl).parentNode) {
      rootEl = Polymer.dom(rootEl).parentNode;
    }

    var tpl = Polymer.dom(rootEl).querySelector('#' + this.ref);
    var tplRoot = tpl.stamp().root;
    this._children = Array.prototype.slice.call(tplRoot.childNodes);
    Polymer.dom(this._parent).insertBefore(tplRoot, this);
  },

  _removeChildren: function() {
    for (var i = 0; i < this._children.length; i++) {
      Polymer.dom(this._parent).removeChild(this._children[i]);
    }
  },

  attached: function() { this._stamp(); },
  detached: function() { this._removeChildren(); },
});
```

The target template element must be a `dom-template` element.

```
<bind-ref ref="howdyTpl"></bind-ref>
<template is="dom-template" id="howdyTpl">Howdy <span>{{whatever}}</span></template>
```

(Code snippets licensed [Apache 2.0](http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0).)

Comment: Sadly, but this works when both bind-ref and template are siblings only. Does not work if bind-ref is inside a <template is="dom-repeat">.

Comment: @miyconst It's working OK for me inside `dom-repeat`. What issue are you seeing? Also, I just fixed it so it removes the stamped elements when detached.

Comment: I am trying to make a custom data-grid component. User should be able to define a custom template for a column. Draft work is available here: http://miyconst.github.io/ct-data-grid/ The Actions column has a template using bind-ref, but the binding does not work inside.

Answer (score 1):

[I've created an element that resolves this problem.](https://github.com/Trakkasure/dom-bindref) It's kind of a hack, but it works... including with multi-depth file inclusion and data binding that the other answer provided did not handle.