# nesting elements and dynamic content inside dom-repeat - Polymer 1.0

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0

I have a `<parent>` element, a `<tabs>` element inside it with an arbitrary number of tabs (purely for hiding/showing logic in the UI), and a `<child>` element inside each `<tab>`. Right now I have the following working:

```
<!-- inside parent.html: -->
<tabs></tabs>

<!-- inside tabs.html: -->
<template is="dom-repeat" items="{{tabs}}" as="tab" index-as="item_no">
    <section>
        <child id="element-{{tab.index}}"></child>
    </section>
</template>
```

Only `<parent>` knows how many instances of `<child>` there needs to be (`<tabs>` merely receives an array from `<parent>` and iterates over it.

Is there a way to *not* hard-code `<child>` inside the local DOM of `<tabs>`? Thinking of using `<content>` and light DOM but no idea where to even start. Would it be a promising route to take?

Desired state:

```
<!-- inside parent.html: -->
<tabs>
    // somehow specify base content to be rendered in each tab
</tabs>

<!-- inside tabs.html: -->
<template is="dom-repeat" items="{{tabs}}" as="tab" index-as="item_no">
    <section>
        // somehow inject stuff from parent element, perhaps via <content>?
    </section>
</template>
```

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34645114/polymer-dom-repeat-binding-to-content

Comment: Could you please extend your question to show your desired way of using your components?

Comment: @alesc Updated, though it's hard to pinpoint exactly since I'm hard-pressed at imagining on how to do it, or if it's even possible. P.S.: Using light DOM is not mandatory, I just need a way to do it, any way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is my interpretation of your question, so I am not really sure if it will be OK with you. If I misunderstood you, please drop a comment and I will gladly update my answer.

I have come up with a simple element composition, requiring no `dom-repeat` or manual template stamping. The solution consists of two custom elements, namely `my-parent` and `my-child`.

The definitions for both custom elements are the following:

```
<dom-module id="my-parent">
  <template>
    <tabs>
      <content></content>
    </tabs>
  </template>
  <script>
    Polymer({
      is: 'my-parent',
    });
  </script>
</dom-module>

<dom-module id="my-child">
  <template>
    <section>
      <content></content>
    </section>
  </template>
  <script>
    Polymer({
      is: 'my-child',
    });
  </script>
</dom-module>
```

And the proposed usage of them is the following:

```
<my-parent>
  <my-child>First tab</my-child>
  <my-child>Second tab</my-child>
  <my-child>Third tab</my-child>
</my-parent>
```

Online demo: http://jsbin.com/hibuzafapu/1/edit?html,output

The resulting computed HTML code looks something like this:

```
<my-parent>
  <tabs>
    <my-child>
      <section>
        First tab
      </section>
    </my-child>
    <my-child>
      <section>
        Second tab
      </section>
    </my-child>
    <my-child>
      <section>
        Third tab
      </section>
    </my-child>
  </tabs>
</my-parent>
```

If I understood you correctly, then only the `<my-child>` tag wrapping the `<section>` tag is redundant. Currently the aforementioned tag does nothing and is just a block-level element that wraps everything (just like a `div`). If this bothers you, then you can actually omit the `<section>` tag and put all the styling directly on the `<my-child>` tag.

In this case, the resulting computed HTML would look something like this:

```
<my-parent>
  <tabs>
    <my-child>
      First tab
    </my-child>
    <my-child>
      Second tab
    </my-child>
    <my-child>
      Third tab
    </my-child>
  </tabs>
</my-parent>
```

---

**UPDATE**

In order to add some dynamics to the solution (adding/removing tabs), you have two options: use `dom-repeat` and stamp the items in light DOM, or push the items array into the `my-parent` element and use `dom-repeat` there. Both options are very similar to implement and don't have much difference in the way they work.

**Option A**: stamping in light DOM:

Definitions for both custom elements remain unchanged, the only difference is how you use them. Instead of hardcoding the light DOM, you make it more dynamic.

```
<dom-module is="tmp-element">
  <template>
    <my-parent>
      <template is="dom-repeat" items="[[myItems]]">
        <my-child>[[item.content]]</my-child>
      </template>
    </my-parent>
  </template>
  <script>
    Polymer({
      is: 'tmp-element',
      ready: function() {
        this.myItems = [
          { content: "First tab" },
          { content: "Second tab" },
          { content: "Third tab" },
        ],
      };
    });
  </script>
</dom-module>

<tmp-element></tmp-element>
```

The `tmp-element` is used purely to create a binding scope and to feed the data into the `dom-repeat`.

Live demo: http://jsbin.com/gafisuwege/1/edit?html,console,output[enter link description here](http://jsbin.com/gafisuwege/1/edit?html,console,output)

**Option B**: stamping inside parent:

In this option, the parent needs to have an additional property, in which will we will supply the array of items.

The new version of the `my-parent` element is the following:

```
<dom-module id="my-parent">
  <template>
    <tabs>
      <template is="dom-repeat" items="[[items]]">
        <my-child>[[item.content]]</my-child>
      </template>
    </tabs>
  </template>
  <script>
    Polymer({
      is: 'my-parent',
      properties: {
        items: Array,
      },
    });
  </script>
</dom-module>
```

And the usage is:

```
<dom-module is="tmp-element">
  <template>
    <my-parent items="[[myItems]]"></my-parent>
  </template>
  <script>
    Polymer({
      is: 'tmp-element',
      ready: function() {
        this.myItems = [
          { content: "First tab" },
          { content: "Second tab" },
          { content: "Third tab" },
        ];
      },
    });
  </script>
</dom-module>

<tmp-element></tmp-element>
```

Here, I have also used a `tmp-element` (a different one than before) to feed the `my-parent` its' data.

Live demo: http://jsbin.com/kiwidaqeki/1/edit?html,console,output

Comment: The issue is that I need that `dom-repeat`, user needs to be able to add/remove tabs dynamically.

Comment: I have updated my answer. I hope it was in the right direction.

Comment: Bingo: Option B is the one I need. Thank you so much for taking the time to help!